# Prevent Visual Studio 2010 MPI cluster debugger from copying all project binaries to temporary user folder before each execution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, mpi

When using Visual Studio 2008 under MPI cluster debugger, each execution is launched without moving the generated binaries (.exe, .lib).

When using Visual Studio 2010 under MPI cluster debugger, each execution is launched by moving the generated binaries (.exe, .lib) in two directories :
- all the .lib are first copied inside the .exe directory
- once done, all the .exe directory is copied inside a temporary directory containing by default the user login name.

So with Visual Studio 2008, each execution of a medium size C++ project takes a few seconds to be launched.
With Visual Studio 2010, each execution of a medium size C++ project takes several minutes.

Is there a way to change the behaviour of Visual Studio 2010 in order to work like Visual Studio 2008 did ?
Or if not possible, is there a way to improve the launching time of each execution ?

I am using MPICH2 for MPI and execute my project only locally (localhost/2 environment with -localonly mpiexec argument), for Visual Studio 2008 and Visual Studio 2010.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: oaimac, what is the actual debugger? How do you start it?

Comment: The debugger is the Cluster MPI debugger of Visual Studio selected inside the project properties dialog box (debug item). The execution envirnment is set to "localhost/2". Deployment dir. is kept empty. Working directory is set to my output exe directory. MPIshim location is set to Visual Studio MPIShim executable. MPIExec command is set to the mpiexec.exe file of the MPICH2 installation directory.  MPIExec argument is set to -localonly. All other parameters are default parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Do review [the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd560807%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that describes the MPI debugger configuration.  Note how the descriptions of the Deployment Directory and Working Directory properties describe what you see.

However, you are not actually debugging on a cluster so you don't need to have these copies made.  Without otherwise knowing what your config looks like, or any way to test it, I'd guess that you have these properties set wrong.  As documented on the page, for local debugging you should select:

- Deployment Directory: none
- Working Directory: the output directory of your project.

Which should avoid the copying.

Comment: I have exactly set these two configuration (deployment directory=None, Working directory=My output dir.). Unfortunately, the 2 copies are still done and non documented treatments seems also to be done after the end of the copies.

Comment: Okay, please put these details in your question so I can delete this post.

Comment: I have put the details inside the preceding answer section. It seems to me your advice should anyway be kept for people that may have the same question than me